# How to write functional tests for POST Api

Tags: rest, spring-boot, functional-testing

I need to write functional tests for the POST api which is simply a callback. I am not able to write the fucntional tests for this

```
@RequestMapping("/api/v1/controller/callback")
@Slf4j
public class DominosController {

    @Autowired
    private PartnerFactory partnerFactory;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/dominos", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public void processDominosCallback(@RequestBody TestCallbackPojo test
CallbackPojo) {
        log.info("Dominos callback received {}", Json.serialize(dominosCallbackPojo));
        partnerFactory.getPartnerService(DeliveryPartnersEnum.DOMINOS.getValue()).processDominosCallback(dominosCallbackPojo);
    }
}
```

This is the processDominosCallback() method.

```
@Override
    public void processDominosCallback(DominosCallbackPojo dominosCallbackPojo) {
        DominosCurrentTracker dominosCurrentTracker = dominosCallbackPojo.getDominosCurrentTracker();
        if (dominosCurrentTracker == null ||  dominosCurrentTracker.getDominosTrackerStage() == null) {
            return;
        }

        PartnerOrderMapping partnerOrderMapping = PartnerOrderMapping.builder()
                .orderId(dominosCallbackPojo.getOrderId())
                .build();

        if (dominosCurrentTracker.getDominosTrackerStage().getValue() == DominosTrackerEnum.ORDER_PUNCH.getValue()) {

            CallbackPojo callbackPojo = CallbackPojo.builder()
                    .orderId(partnerOrderMapping.getOrderId())
                    .orderStatus(DominosStatusEnum.CONFIRMED.getValue())
                    .deliveryPartnersEnum(DeliveryPartnersEnum.DOMINOS)
                    .build();

            partnerStatusUpdateService.processDeConfirmed(callbackPojo);
            return;
        }
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to test? I understand that you are trying to write a functional test for the processDominosCallback method. But what is the important functionality of this method?

Comment: Got reoslved for this.

Comment: If you have resolved this issue then please consider adding the solution for others who come across your question while looking for answers to their own problems.